# HTML tag formatting php and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have this MySQL statement

```
Select type.type, color.color, ShotName, Item.name, Item.Item_id
  From type 
    Inner Join Item 
      On type.type_id =Item.type_id 
    Inner Join color 
      On color.color_id =Item.color_id 
  Where Item.state=0 And Item.offline = 0
  Group By color.color, Item.name, type.order_nr
  Order By type_D.order_nr, color.color, Item.name_d
```

How can do this with php to get a result formatted as the following HTML? I have managed to list the items but I am not able to put `<ul>` properly

```
<body>
  <h2> Type AA </h2>
  <h3> color black </h3>
  <ul>
    <li> ShortName 1 name 1</li>
    <li> ShortName 2 name 2</li>
    <li> ShortName 3 name 3</li>
    <li> ShortName 4 name 4</li>
    <li> ShortName 5 name 5</li>
  </ul>
  <h3> color green </h3>
  <ul>
    <li> ShortName 7 name 7</li>
    <li> ShortName 8 name 8</li>
    <li> ShortName 9 name 9</li>
    <li> ShortName 10 name 10</li>
    <li> ShortName 11 name 11</li>
  </ul>
  <h2> Type AB </h2>
  <h3> color black </h3>
  <ul>
    <li> ShortName 12 name 12</li>
    <li> ShortName 13 name 13</li>
    <li> ShortName 14 name 14</li>
    <li> ShortName 15name 15</li>
    <li> ShortName 16name 16</li>
  </ul>
  <h3> color green </h3>
  <ul>
    <li> ShortName 17 name 17</li>
    <li> ShortName 18 name 18</li>
    <li> ShortName 19 name 19</li>
    <li> ShortName 20 name 20</li>
    <li> ShortName 22 name 22</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Here is my PHP code

```
$myfile = mysql_query($query_myfile, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_myfile = mysql_num_rows($myfile);

while ( $row_myfile = mysql_fetch_assoc($myfile) ) 
{
    if ( $type != $row_myfile[ 'type' ] ) 
    {

        $type = $row_myfile[ 'type' ];

        echo "<h2>$type</h2>";

    }
    if ( $color != $row_myfile[ 'color' ] ) 
    {

        $color = $row_myfile[ 'color' ];

        echo "<h3>$color</h3>";
    }

    echo "<li><a href=\"itemDetail.php?item_id=".$row_myfile['myfile_id']. "\">";
    echo $row_myfile['ShortName'].' ';
    echo $row_myfile['name']; ?></a></li>
```

Comment: thanx but the counter goes only to 5 ..i can have more or less

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements. Note that `or die(mysql_error())` should never appear in production code, as [`die`](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die) breaks HTML output and database error messages should never be revealed to non-admin users as it [discloses too much information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995351.aspx#securityerrormessages_topic2). A better approach would be to properly implement error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add more things you want to display in the li-tag

```
$sql = "copy your sql";

$result_set = $result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<body>";
$type = false;
$color = false;
$close_ul = false;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($type != $row['type']) {
        if ($close_ul) { 
            echo "</ul>"; 
            $close_ul = false;
        }
        $type = $row['type'];
        echo "<h2>$type</h2>";
        $color = false;
    }
    if ($color != $row['color']) {
        if ($close_ul) { 
            echo "</ul>"; 
            $close_ul = false;
        }
        $color = $row['color'];
        echo "<h3>$color</h3>";
        echo "<ul>";
        $close_ul = true;
    }

    echo "<li>",$row['shortname'],"</li>";
}
if ($close_ul) { 
    echo "</ul>"; 
    $close_ul = false;
}
echo "</body>";
```

Comment: thanx a lot but i am getting this error syntax error, unexpected 'EOF'

Comment: that means the there is a } or something missing, or a ' " .... maybe a copy and paste error ..

Comment: can you post your complete file

Comment: corrected but now i am getting this </h3></ul><li> it should be rather </h3><ul><li>. all ul are closing, no opening <ul>

Comment: is an opening <ul> `echo "<h3>$color</h3>";
    echo "<ul>";`

Answer (score 0):

contact your html properly. Here is the solution.

```
while ( $row_myfile = mysql_fetch_assoc($myfile) ){

                if ( $type != $row_myfile[ 'type' ] ) 
                {

                    $type = $row_myfile[ 'type' ];

                    echo "<h2>$type</h2>";

                }
                if ( $color != $row_myfile[ 'color' ] ) 
                {

                    $color = $row_myfile[ 'color' ];

                    echo "<h3>$color</h3>";
                }

                echo "<ul>"; 
                echo "<li>";                
                echo "<a href='itemDetail.php?item_id='$row_myfile['myfile_id']'>ShortName ".$row_myfile['ShortName']." Name " .$row_myfile['name']." </a>";               
                echo "</li>";
                echo "</ul>";
            }
```